# IntelliJ IDEA needs permission to open in Mac OS

Tags: intellij-idea, macos-sierra

I have use IntelliJ for the development and it's always need permission to open in the Mac OS Sierra.

[image]

I have changed the settings in the `Security and Privacy` to `Allow apps downloaded from - app store and identified developers` and its behaves still the same.

I have followed the steps to provide an exception for opening,

```
To override your security settings and open the app anyway:

a. In the Finder, locate the app you want to open.

b. Don’t use Launchpad to do this. Launchpad doesn’t allow you to access the shortcut menu.

c. Press the Control key, then click the app icon, then choose Open from the shortcut menu.

d. Click Open.

The app is saved as an exception to your security settings, and you can open it in the future by double-clicking it just as you can any registered app.
```

However, it doesn't help at all. How do I open it with only by double clicking?

[image]

Comment: Go into Finder -> Applications -> Right click on the app and click "Open" it will allow you to open it from there.

Comment: Did you drag it into Applications folder from the .dmg? Do you start it from Applications?

Comment: `a. ` Yes. 
`b. `  I have open from the Applications, didn't help me. Now do it from the Dock by double clicking. 
I use Mac OS for a while, but, this is new machine.\